# how does python manage object memory

Tags: python, memory-management

It feels like Python handles the memory differently in the following two cases:

**case 1**

```
import numpy as np
while True:
    array = np.ones((10000, 10000))
```

**case 2**

```
import mediapipe as mp
while True:
    faceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(False, 3, True, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Case 1 does not cause memory overflow at all, however, case 2 does populate RAM very quickly. Could you please help explain how python manages the memory usage here and why case 1 does not cause overflow while case 2 does?

Comment: Use of [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), probably.

Comment: @accessviolation I don't think numpy uses generators for things like this.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that mediapipe keeps a history of the objects it has created. Otherwise the objects should become garbage when the variable is reassigned, and the garbage collector should reclaim the memory.

Comment: @Barmar that's my guess as well. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I'm not familiar with MediaPipe. But since it's for machine learning, the memory could be all the knowledge that it's building up.

Comment: `numpy` is not Python, it's an extension module written by a third-party — so how it does things doesn't necessarily have anything to do with how the interpreter does them.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Python uses reference counters.  When you run `variable = value1`, the reference counter for `value1` gets incremented.  When you then run `variable = value2`, the reference count for `value1` is decremented and for `value2 is incremented.  If the count on` value1` goes down to zero, it can be deleted.

Anything else depends on the system and the module.  It appears that numpy frees the space immediately.  There are never more than 2 arrays alive at any instance.  I have no idea what mediapipe is doing.

Comment: "It appears that NumPy frees the space immediately." I think you meant to say that python freed the space occupied by NumPy (value1) immediately since ```` variable = value2```` breaks the reference of ````variable```` to value2. I am not sure this is what python garbage collector does. However, this does not work in the same way for mediapipe.

Comment: @AlbertGLieu.  I was trying to avoid too much detail.